# Why is the set $\{1,\sqrt {2}\}$ linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ but not over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Why is the set $\{1,\sqrt {2}\}$ linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ but linearly dependent over $\mathbb R$?

I have only come across these types of questions with vectors, how would you go about showing this?

Comment: Can you solve $a \cdot 1 + b \cdot \sqrt{2} = 0$ if $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$? Can you solve it if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$? This is the difference.

Comment: Because $\sqrt 2$ is real but not rational.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$ you can write $\sqrt{2}\cdot\mathbf{1}-1\cdot\mathbf{\sqrt{2}}=\mathbf{0}$ where the bold part are the vectors and the non-bold the scalars.

Comment: A field is a vector space over any subfield, so this *is* a "question with vectors."

Answer (score 2):

That is because $\sqrt 2$ is irrational: if $1$ and $\sqrt 2$ were linearly dependent, $\sqrt 2$ would be  rational.

On the other hand, $\mathbf R$  has dimension $1$ over itself, so any two real numbers are linearly dependent.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ have dimension $1$, but $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ have dimention $\mathfrak{c}$.